# The unique index of an ArrayField regardless of the position of elements in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, peewee

```
class Marriage(BaseModel):
    users = ArrayField(BigIntegerField)
    chat_id = BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('users', "chat_id"), True),
        )
```

I would like to make a unique index for both user values and chat_id for example:

## there is already such a row in the database:

```
users=[1,2], chat_id=1
```

## I would like to create the same but a different position in the user array.

```
users=[2,1], chat_id=1
```

## I need this "duplicate key value violates" to work as well, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest consulting the Postgres folks as I'm not sure how you'd do that. I think the "best" solution is to store them flat:

```py
class Marriage(BaseModel):
    chat_id = pw.BigIntegerField()
    user_id = pw.BigIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('chat_id', 'user_id'), True),
        )

for uid in (1, 2):
    Marriage.create(user_id=uid, chat_id=1)
```

Then to get all users for a marriage:

```
q = Marriage.select(Marriage.user_id).where(Marriage.chat_id == 1)
uids = [uid for uid, in q.tuples()]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Postgres you create a *unique index* and order the values of (user_id, chat_id) using the [least(), greatest()](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/postgresql/greatest-least-function) functions as follows: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/N7HN8HAH))

```
create unique  index chat_user_same_ndx 
    on marriage( least(chat_id, user_id), greatest(chat_id, user_id) );
```

I am not sure how this exactly translates into your obscurification language. But would seem doable looking how you created the index in your code.